# Close jquery ui popup with text link

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

I have a problem with the jquery-ui pop up dialog. 
if i close with default popup close button ok, but if i close with text link then pop up not close.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#popup').live('click', function (e) {
        var page = $(this).attr("href")
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')

    .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: '500',
        width: '85%',
        title: "",

        buttons: {
            "Close": function () { 
                $dialog.dialog('close'); 
                location.reload();
             }
        },
    });
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});


$("#close").live("click", function (e) {
   alert('hjhhh');
   $dialog.dialog('close');
});

call from html
<a id="close" href="#">close popup</a>
```

thanks a lot before

Answer (score 0):

`$dialog` is not on the `$("#close")` function scope.
Try to declare `var $dialog` under `$(document).ready` function out side of `$('a#popup')`

Comment: if i want use $('a#popup') how can i close it from text link?

Comment: @user1409709 You can put `$("#close")` function inside the `$('a#popup')` function

Comment: brother bitoshi.n i try your suggestion to put $("#close").live("click", function (e) {
   alert('hjhhh');
   $dialog.dialog('close');
}); inside $('a#popup') but popup can't close after click text link, i put it before last });

Comment: @user1409709 Ok, I hope you have [read this faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if you have got answer of your question.

Comment: thanks a lot brother bitoshi.n <BR> I've just found the solution with add var session;

 function retriveSession(data){
  session = data;
 }
 
   $(document).ready(function () {
  $('a#popup').live('click', function (e) {
   $.get('check_session.asp', retriveSession);
   
   if (session == '') {
    location.reload();
   } .... <BR> and then create check_session.asp with <BR>  if session("loguser")=false then
  response.write "expired"
 end if